# how can i display data in detail component from list component?

Tags: angular, api, components, observable

i have problem to display data from one component to another component.
i put the data which i fetch from the serve in prova and i display the list of all work. but I can't transfer the data that is on "prova" to another component to make the details visible through their own id.

**this is my apicall service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpClientModule,HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
import {results} from "./results"


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetApiService {

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient,
  ) { }


  apiCall():Observable<results[]>
  {
    return this.http.get('https://www.themuse.com/api/public/jobs?category=Engineering&page=10')
    .pipe(map
    (
      (response:any) => {
        const data = response.results;
        console.log (data)
        return data ;
   
      }
    )
    );
   }
}
```

**this is my observable results**

```
  export interface results
    {
  categories : any;
company: string;
contents:string;
id : number;
 levels:string;
 locations:string;
 model_type: string;
 name: string;
 refs: string;
 short_name: string;
 type:string;

  }
```

**this is my component where are a list of works**

```
import {results} from "../results";
import {GetApiService} from '../get-api.service';
import {switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-work-list',
  templateUrl: './work-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./work-list.component.css']
})
export class WorkListComponent implements OnInit {
   
  prova: results[]=[] ;
 item: any;
  selectedId: any ;
  constructor(
    private api :GetApiService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.api.apiCall()
    .subscribe
      (
        (data:results[]) => {
          this.prova=data;
        console.log (data);

        });

}
}
```

**and the respectiv html connected by id**

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of prova " 
    [class.selected]="item.id === selectedId">
                      
    <a
    [routerLink]="['/details',item.id]">
    <h1> {{ item.name }}</h1>
    </a>
    <h1> {{ item.id }}</h1>
    <h1> {{ item.categories[0].name }}</h1>
    <h1> {{ item.name }}</h1>

      </div>
```

**this is the details where i can't display the selected work with its own details**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {results}  from '../results';
import {GetApiService} from '../get-api.service';
import {switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";


@Component({
selector: 'app-work-details',
templateUrl: './work-details.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./work-details.component.css']
})
export class WorkDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
@Input()
item: {
  categories: any;
  company: string;
  contents: string;
  id: number;
  levels: string;
  locations: string;
  model_type: string;
  name: string;
  refs: string;
  short_name: string;
  type: string;
} | undefined;
@Input ()
prova: results[]=[];
selectedId:string | undefined;
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private api: GetApiService,
) { }

ngOnInit():void {

   this.route.paramMap.subscribe
    (params => {
      this.item=this.prova[+params.get('selectedId')];

**// it should  be somewthing like this but prova is empty.**
      
    })
  ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're mixing two different mechanisms?

One is of a parent -> child component relationship where you have your `WorkDetailsComponent` with an `@Input()` for `prova`, but at the same time, it looks like the component is its own page given your `<a [routerLink]="['/details',item.id]">` and the usage of `this.route.paramMap.subscribe...`.

Fairly certain you can't have it both ways.

You either go parent -> child component wherein you pass in the relevant details using the `@Input()`s:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedItem">
  <app-work-details [prova]="prova" [selectedItem]="selectedItem"></app-work-details>
</div>
```

OR you go with the separate page route which can be done one of two ways:

1. Use the service as a shared service; have it remember the state (`prova`) so that when the details page loads, it can request the data for the relevant id.
2. Pass the additional data through the route params

For 1, it would look something like:

```
private prova: results[]; // Save request response to this as well

public getItem(id: number): results {
  return this.prova.find(x => x.id === id);
}
```

And then when you load your details page:

```
ngOnInit():void {

   this.route.paramMap.subscribe
    (params => {
      this.selectedId=+params.get('selectedId');

   this.item = this.service.getItem(this.selectedId);
      
    });
}
```

For 2, it involves routing with additional data, something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/details',item.id]" [state]="{ data: {prova}}">..</a>
```

This [article](https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255) shows the various ways of getting data between components in better detail.